# How do you prove a radical is a circle on the Cartesian plane?

Tags: proof-writing, graphing-functions, radicals

I know something like $ \sqrt{x^{2}-1}$ could be a circle because that's just what I've always been told and it relates to the Pythagorean theorem. But, I looked at $ \sqrt{-(x-1)x}.$ I know that certainly looks like a circle, and it probably is, but how do I know for sure it's a circle in the Cartesian plane?

Comment: No, I think I made a mistake earlier. $y=\sqrt{x^2-1}$ is not the equation of a circle. It is of a hyperbola.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that $y=\sqrt{x^2-1}$ is not a circle. It is a hyperbola because after squaring, you get $x^2-y^2=1$ which is the equation of a hyperbola. Plus, since $y$ has to be non-negative, it can't be all of the hyperbola given by that equation, but only the half of the two branches of the hyperbola that are in the upper half of the plane.

For the second equation, again, note that it can't be a complete circle because we know that $y$ has to be non-negative. By squaring, you get

$$y^2 = -x^2 -x = -(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{1}{4}$$

Therefore, $$(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+y^2=\frac{1}{4}$$

which is the equation of a circle centered at $(-\frac{1}{2},0)$ with radius $\frac{1}{2}$, but since $y$ has to be positive, it gives you only the upper half of the circle, not the rest.

One other way to see that it can't be a complete circle is to note that your equation defines $y$ as a function of $x$ and that means that its graph must pass the vertical line test. Therefore, it can't be a complete circle.

Please note that a circle is defined as the set of points that are at a fixed distance away from a point called the center. Knowing that distance in the plane for the two points $(x,y)$ and $(a,b)$ is defined as $\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}$, the equation of a circle centered at $(a,b)$ with radius $R$ is then translated to:

$$\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}=R$$
$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=R^2$$

That's why $(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+y^2=\frac{1}{4}$ is in the form of the equation of a circle centered at $(-\frac{1}{2},0)$ with radius $\frac{1}{2}$, and the set of our points would've been a circle had we not have any restricting conditions on $y$. But since we do know that $y$ is non-negative, we have to restrict it to where $y$ is non-negative, which is the upper half of the plane.

Comment: It seems like you contradicted yourself. You said "it can't be a complete circle" and then you said "Therefore...it's a circle." I would imagine that proving it's a circle would have something to do with proving it has a constant radius?

Comment: I never said that it's a circle. The equation has the form of the equation of a circle, but since $y$ is non-negative, it won't give you all the points $(x,y)$ that satisfy the equation, but only the ones with non-negative $y$. And it does have a constant radius, the radius is $\frac{1}{2}$. Does that clear it up?

Comment: Right but see you're simply saying it has a constant radius. We already know people arbitrarily say "this radical is a circle" as a given without explanation, but what's being done to prove it? Also the imaginary part is a circle which is what I was thinking, but you're otherwise right so I corrected the second expression.

Comment: You literally said "which is the equation of a circle centered at (−12,0)(−12,0)" So yeah, I would say you said it's a circle.

Comment: @james: By definition, a circle is the set of points that are at a constant distance away from a point that is called the center. If you look at the equation $x^2+y^2=r^2$, you see that by the Pythagorean theorem (and the definition of distance in $r^2$) this has to give you a circle centered at $(0,0)$ of radius $r$ because any point satisfying this equation is $r$ units away from the origin. The same is true if we shift the circle to other points. Right?

Comment: @james: I said "the equation" is the equation of a circle. Not the set of points that satisfy our conditions. Therefore, I never said that what we have a circle. :)

Comment: @james: I added more explanations for you. Let me know if you still had more doubts.

Answer (score 0):

By definition a circle is a set of points which are a fixed distance away from some fixed point called the center. In the language of coordinates: a set $S$, whose elements are ordered pairs, forms a circle only if there are constants $h, k, r$ such that every ordered pair $(x_0, y_0) \in S$ saitsfies

$$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2$$

Note that the above is a neccesary but not sufficient for the point of $S$ to form a circle; the set $S = \{(0, -1), (0, 1)\}$ sastisfies the above condition with $h=0, k=0, r=1$, but it doe not describe a circle).

Now we wish to determine if the points of $S=\{(x, y)| \ $ $y= \sqrt{-x^2-x } \ \}$ form a circle; we have to answer: do there exist constants $h, k, r$ such that $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2$ for every $(x, y)\in S$? Looking at the graph for inspiration, we can see that $h=-0.5, k=0, r=0.5$ might work; and indeed they do:

Take any $(x_0, y_0) \in S$. We want to show that this pair satisfies $(x_0+0.5)^2+ y_0^2=0.5^2$. And indeed it does;

$(x_0+0.5)^2+ y_0^2$

$=x_0^2+x_0+0.5^2+(\sqrt {-x^2-x})^2$

$=x_0^2+x_0+0.5^2+|-x^2-x|$

$=x_0^2+x_0+0.5^2-x_0^2-x_0$

$=0.5^2$

Thus $S$ is the subset of some circle. We already knew from the graph that it wasn't going to be a full circle; but we also haven't proved that it doesn't contain any holes.

Answer (score -1):

$-x^2-x=\frac{1}{4}-(\frac{1}{4}+x+x^2)=\frac{1}{4}-(x+\frac{1}{2})^2$. Therefore, your equation is a circle with center $(-\frac{1}{2},0)$ and radius $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Please note that $y$ cannot be negative. Therefore, it won't give a complete circle. Moreover, since $y=\sqrt{-x^2-x}$ is indeed a well-defined function of $x$, again it can't be a complete circle since then it will fail the vertical line test for being a function.

Comment: Of course it is not a circle, because a circle is not even a function. I just showed you the radius and the center of the upper half you defined with that equation. the other half is the same square root, but with a negative sign in front of it.

Comment: I'm not the OP. I'm just pointing out that your last sentence, saying "your equation is a circle ..." is wrong.